# Extract frame from MP4 without FFMPEG

Tags: php, video, html5-video, mp4

I'm running a php site on shared hosting, so FFMPEG isn't available. What other options do I have for extracting the first frame as a JPG when a user uploads a video file.

Comment: You'll have to create a `<video>` and a `<canvas>` then use Javascript to draw the video element into canvas which it turn can output a JPG or PNG. You can add HTML/JS inside a PHP file and have PHP call the JS functions (eg: a function to create the elements dynamically by code & also draw and export the encoded mage bytes. Finally a PHP function uploads the image data (bytes) to your server.

Comment: If you are able to install PHP libraries, you can use OpenCV to extract the frame s form the video - https://github.com/php-opencv/php-opencv